# Jquery.getJSON is not able to handle cross browser between domain though it should be

Tags: jquery, ajax, getjson

I am trying to create a jquery widget which loads some data from the server and put it in a container in clients browser. So the issue of cross browser call in different domain needs to be taken care of. To do so I used  $.getJSON. The following shows my javascript code:

```
(function() {

// Localize jQuery variable
var jQuery;

/** ****** Load jQuery if not present ******** */
if (window.jQuery === undefined || window.jQuery.fn.jquery !== '1.4.2') {
    var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
    script_tag.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
    script_tag
            .setAttribute("src",
                    "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js");
    if (script_tag.readyState) {
        script_tag.onreadystatechange = function() { // For old versions
                                                        // of IE
            if (this.readyState == 'complete'
                    || this.readyState == 'loaded') {
                scriptLoadHandler();
            }
        };
    } else { // Other browsers
        script_tag.onload = scriptLoadHandler;
    }
    // Try to find the head, otherwise default to the documentElement
    (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement)
            .appendChild(script_tag);
} else {
    // The jQuery version on the window is the one we want to use
    jQuery = window.jQuery;
    main();
}

/** ****** Called once jQuery has loaded ***** */
function scriptLoadHandler() {
    // Restore $ and window.jQuery to their previous values and store the
    // new jQuery in our local jQuery variable
    jQuery = window.jQuery.noConflict(true);
    // Call our main function
    main();
}

/** ****** Our main function ******* */
function main() {
    jQuery(document)
            .ready(
                    function($) {
                        getTodaysAd();
                        function getTodaysAd() {
                            var url = "http://localhost:8080/TJ/ads/adsLoader";
                            $
                                    .getJSON(
                                            url,
                                            function(data) {
                                                console.log(data);
                                                $("#todaysAd")
                                                        .append(
                                                                "<a id=\"adsDestination\"><img id=\"adsImg\"></a></img>");
                                                $("#adsImg").attr({
                                                    "href" : data[0].href,
                                                    "src" : data[0].imgurl
                                                });
                                                $("#adsDestination").attr({
                                                    "href" : data[0].href
                                                });
                                            });
                        }

                    });
    }

  })(function() {
  }); // We call our anonymous function immediately
```

and in order to run it user just need to add the following to the page:

```
<script src="http://localhost:8080/TJ/js/embed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="todaysAd" class="panel-heading"></div>
```

However still I get the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/TJ/ads/adsLoader. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3003' is therefore not allowed access.
```

But as I searched $.getJSON should be able to handle this issue. Can anyone help?

******************UPDATE***************************

When I do the same thing but in the same domain everything works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `$.getJSON` will in fact work cross-domain, you have to make sure that the domain you're fetching from is properly set up to allow the request.

As the error states, this can be accomplished by putting an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header on the domain you're trying to fetch from.

For more information about adding this header, take a look at this answer: [How does Access-Control-Allow-Origin header work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work)

Comment: For those who are using apache tomcat this link can be useful for setting up the web.xml: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter

Comment: Thanks for accepting, and nice of you to include some additional information.